# Is there a way where I can plot data from a CSV file where every 10 data points in a column are a different line in the same graph?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv, matplotlib

Say I have a data set that is in two columns. I want to plot a line plot iterating through every 10. So, I would take the first 10, and then the second 10, which is right under the first 10, for another line plot on the same graph (different color line). The data is stacked on each other in a CSV file with no header.

Currently, I have it taking in the entire column. It plots them, however there is no differentiation as to which data set it is. I want to plot multiple lines on the same graph but the CSV file has all the data sets in one column, but I need to graph every 10.

**EDIT**
Below I have Data added I would like the first column to be the x-axis and the second to be the y.

```
Sample Data:
0   8.2
1   9.1
2   2.2
3   3.3
4   9.8
5   6.3
6   4.8
7   8.6
8   3.9
9   2.1
0   9.34
1   10.2
2   7.22
3   6.98
4   1.34
5   2.56
6   6.78
7   4.56
8   3.3
9   9.4
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: Yes, there is some way. But that depends much on your data and your desired output. So provide some sample just as @ScottBoston says.

Comment: @ScottBoston I added some sample data

Comment: @QuangHoang Ok, I added some sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, try this:

```
# this is the toy data
df = pd.DataFrame({0:list(range(10))*2,
                1:np.random.uniform(9,11,20)})

# set up axes for plots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

# the groupby argument groups every 10 rows together
# then pass it to the `lambda` function,
# which plots each chunk to the given plt axis
df.groupby(df.reset_index().index//10).apply(lambda x: ax.plot(x[0], x[1]) )
plt.show()
```

[image]

## Option 2:

I found `sns` is a better tool for the purpose:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10,6))
sns.lineplot(x=df[0], 
             y=df[1], 
             hue=df.reset_index().index//10, 
             data=df,
             palette='Set1')
plt.show()
```

outputs:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what is exactly happening?

Comment: What does the first line exactly do? Right now, I have my data being read in by pd.read_csv(file, use_cols = [1, 3], header = None)

Comment: So would it be df.groupby(df.reset_index().index//10?
Should I set this equal to something so that I can make a legend for it?

Comment: So would you change the legend name by sns.legend? Because they are appearing as 0 1 2

Comment: Also, say you don't know how many iterations of 10 there are, thus you have to write a for loop for the legend by iterating. So first line would be "test1" second "test2" and so on with the number iterating. I'm a little confused on this part too

Comment: Dean: you need to solve that problem first. Then you would have a column name `label` like `[test1, test1,..., test2,...]` which you can pass to `hue=df['label']` and legend will be as you wish.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you mean by that I am having confusion. I am running into some issues. I am able to plot the plot however, the legend is showing "0, 3, 6, 9" I want it to show Test#. # being the iterator for every 10 numbers iterating 1 time. Also, I have multiple csv files in my directory but it breaks when I put another csv file there.